# UserControl Designer mess?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a couple of `Visual Studio Express 2010` projects which contain `UserControls` in the main `namespace`. The projects are checked in my `perforce-versioning server` (including `.suo`, `.sln`, `app.config` and all files in `My Project`).

Whenever I check out the project in a different `workspace` than the last I edited the project in, I get the Designer-error:

`Variable not declared : ("Warning  4   Die Variable XXX wurde nicht deklariert oder nicht zugeordnet.  C:\Documents and Settings\bla\Desktop\Workspace\VB\my_project\my_project\Main.Designer.vb")`

Could this be, because of the different absolute path of my project?
Rebuilding the project doesn't help here.

The only solution is to change the `Zielframework` (target framework?) to `.NET Framework X Client Profile` and then back to `.NET Framework X`.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: VS2010 had trouble with the client profile, it interacted very poorly with IntelliSense.  Particularly when some projects target the Client profile and some target the full version.  Probably has something to do with it.  Excising the Client profile from all projects is strongly recommended.  Getting stuck on a 4 year old version of a free tool is an uncommon hangup btw.